# Python gives broken pipe error and unable to write error while using os module

Tags: python, bash, os.system

```
import os 
cmd='for file in /proc/*/status ; do awk \'/VmSwap/||/^Pid/||/Name/{printf "%-20s", $2 $3}END{ print""}\' $file; done | sort -nr -k 3  | head -5'
os.system(cmd)
```

## output, i have added # , my question is , why am i getting broken pipe error , last two lines.

## >>> res = os.system(cmd)

## sort: write failed: standard output: Broken pipe

## sort: write error

Comment: Use `subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)` or better yet just do it in pure python, there is nothing in your cmd that python cannot do

Comment: @pardraic  , I directing output of different command to a file and using subprocess to write to single file makes difficult due to creation of child process and each child process tries to write to the file at the same time affecting the sequence in which that has to be written . please see if you can do with os.system .

Comment: does adding `| dd obs=1M` before `| head -n 5` work?

Comment: @Padraic. I will use subprocess and store the results in some temp file and later I will add them . dd obs=1M didn't work .

Comment: It works for me, what OS are you using? Why don't you just redirect stdout to  a file?